# Socket_recv MSG_WAITALL does not read full length

Tags: php, sockets

I'm receiveing a socket response, in which the first 4 bytes are a packed int indicating the legnth of the message to recieve. We are receiving through `MSG_WAITALL` and it only recieves certain number of bytes before closing the connection. PHP Manual says this is normal "if a signal is caught". How would I get the full message, which is `$i["val"]` long?

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_connect($sock , $server , 4656);
socket_recv($sock, $i, 4, MSG_WAITALL);
$i=unpack('Nval', $i);
socket_recv($sock, $buf, $i["val"], MSG_WAITALL);
```

Specifically it only reads 2916bytes. If `$i["val"]` is less than that, it reads correctly, otherwise a max of 2916 bytes.

Even when I loop, it won't read correctly, unless I loop through at 1byte at a time, which I think is not the proper way of doing it. Here's a loop at 2045b/loop.

```
$len=$i[val];
echo 'Total Len: ' . $len . PHP_EOL;
if($len>=2045){
    $loops=floor($len/2045);
    echo 'Total Loops: ' . $loops . PHP_EOL;
    $last_loop=$len-(2045*$loops);
    echo 'Last Loop: ' . $last_loop . PHP_EOL;
    for($x=1; $x<=$loops; $x++){
        socket_recv($sock, $buf, 2045, MSG_WAITALL);
        $reply.=$buf;
    }
    socket_recv($sock, $buf, $last_loop, MSG_WAITALL);
    $reply.=$buf;
}else{
    socket_recv($sock, $buf, $len, MSG_WAITALL);
    $reply.=$buf;
}
echo 'Total Received: ' . strlen($reply) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: You need to call `socket_recv` in a loop until it returns false.

Comment: The loop will never return false, because it always sends data, either requested or PING, so that won't work.

Comment: Then you need to call `socket_recv` in a loop until the total length of received data is at least equal to your expected value. Perhaps don't use `MSG_WAITALL`. I'm far from an expert at sockets, and it's been a while since I've worked with them, so take my advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: I tried that, and I still don't get the expected result because of this "if a signal is caught" of php. The only way I have been able to get the full message so far is through getting 1 character at a time, which is not so practical.

Comment: Did you try it without `MSG_WAITALL`?

Comment: yes, none work. MSG_WAITALL get's the closest, and that doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you add your loop code attempt to the question? It seems like you're using `MSG_WAITALL` only as a substitute for looping `socket_recv`.

Comment: I updated the message with my looping. Should I post the single character loop as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some untested code:

```
<?php

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_connect($sock, $server, 4656);

$len = 0;
$reply = '';

do {
    $status = socket_recv($sock, $buffer, 2048, 0);

    if (!$len) {
        $i = unpack('Nval', substr($buffer, 0, 4));
        $len = $i['val'];
        $buffer = substr($buffer, 4);
        echo 'Total Len: ' . $len . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $reply .= $buffer;

    if ($status === false) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        echo 'socket: [' . $errorcode . ']' . $errormsg . PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
} while (strlen($reply) < $len);

echo 'Total Received: ' . strlen($reply) . PHP_EOL;

?>
```